# Backup sump pump discharge too big

Tags: plumbing, sump-pump

After living in a house for a year, I noticed my backup sump pump discharge pipe is 1 1/2", but then changes to 2" before it goes outside.  It changes to 2" about 2/3 up the vertical section.  The pump runs OK when tested but I'm worried in case of a real emergency that it'll burn out quick.

Am I being paranoid?  Has anyone seen a battery backup pump with a 2" discharge?

Answer (score 1):

I fail to see a problem here. Increasing the discharge pipe diameter does not increase the load on the pump. Unless you have a pump manual that specifically forbids this (which seems **very** unlikely) relax and stop worrying about it - or worry about the battery running out, which is far more likely to be a problem in any extended power outage.

If you have such an unlikely manual, replace the pipe that offends you/it.

Comment: Indeed. If anything the larger pipe diameter reduces the load on the pump by reducing the frictional losses in the pipe, and therefore reducing the backpressure.